# ViewPager and Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i have a ViewPager which contains 3 fragments, the problem is that each fragment has a different height. In the ViewPager i have tried to use wrap_content for the height but it doesn't work.

**Edit**

What i need to do is to have the ViewPager to resize when i switch trough the fragments.

any idea ?

Comment: would u plz post piece of ur code??

Comment: i don't thin the code is going to help, is a simple ViewPager with some fragment with different height.

Comment: Try setting the height to match_parent then.

Comment: did u try or not... code will tell that... and what u hv tried.. that aslo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the height within the view pager, not the xml.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){

        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int height = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {

            View child = getChildAt(i);

            child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

            int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();

            if(h > height) height = h;

        }

        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Playing around with onMeasure method will get you what you need, the Viewpager is controlling the height +  width of its children

If that doesn't work , you can overide the getPageHeight and GetPagewidth methods of the View Pager

```
  @Override
        public float getPageHeight(int position) {
         //Return different height based on position.
        // Height is returned as a float
             if(position == 1)
              {
                  return (0.35f);
               }
             else{
                  retrun 0.50f;
                  }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

By telling the `ViewPager` to `wrap_content` its height will be the largest of the fragments. Then if you have other fragments that are shorter than the tallest fragment they will appear shorter inside the `ViewPager`. The `ViewPager` holds all three fragments at once - it doesn't remove the fragments one to the left and right because they need to be ready to move in.

Hence the `ViewPager`'s height is always that of the tallest Fragment. Instead, you could set all the fragments' heights to `match_parent` and the `ViewPager`'s to the size of its parent (using `match_parent`) or try and fit it to the maximum fragment's height using `wrap_content`(though I don't know how this will work when using `wrap_content` and `match_parent` together)